# Show that $f$ can be extended to a bounded linear functional on $C([a, b])$ if and only if $0 \in [a, b]$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the space $Y$ of polynomials as a linear subspace of $C([a, b])$. Define a linear functional on $Y$ as follows: $f(a_nx^n+...+a_0) = a_0$. Show that $f$ can be extended to a bounded linear functional on $C([a, b])$ if and only if $0 \in [a, b]$.

Comment: What is your definition of $f$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Oh, sorry, I missed it. Just edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $p_n(x)=(2x-a-b)^n.$ Then $\|p_n\|_\infty =(b-a)^n$ and $|p_n(0)|=|a+b|^n.$ If $0\notin [a,b],$ then $a,b$ are nonzero numbers with the same sign. Hence $|b+a|>b-a.$ Therefore $${|p_n(0)|\over \|p_n\|_\infty} {\longrightarrow} \infty$$

For $0\in [a,b]$ the functional $f\mapsto f(0)$ defines the unique extension.